# Converting html date and time to my database datetime column

Tags: php, html, mysql

These are my html inputs

```
<input id="6" type="date" name="start_date">
<input id="7" type="time" name="start_time"><br>
<input id="8" type="date" name="end_date">
<input id="9" type="time" name="end_time"><br>
```

Then I use the post method to claim them like this

```
$start_date = (string) $_POST['start_date'];
$start_time = (string) $_POST['start_time'];
$end_date = (string) $_POST['end_date'];
$end_time = (string) $_POST['end_time'];
```

and finally execute the query like this

```
$dateTimeStart="$start_date.' '.$start_time";
$dateTimeEnd="$end_date.' '.$end_time";
$dateTimeStart = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($dateTimeStart));
$dateTimeEnd = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($dateTimeEndime));
$sql="INSERT INTO appointment (prof_id, student_id, app_start, app_end) VALUES ('$prof_id', '(SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE firstname='$stud_first' AND lastname='$stud_last')', '$dateTimeStart', '$dateTimeEnd');";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

But there seems to be something wrong.. can u help me?

Comment: You're already using an API that supports **prepared statements** with bounded variable input, you should utilize parameterized queries with placeholders (prepared statements) to protect your database against [SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)!
 Get started with [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) and [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param).

Comment: Use PHP error-reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get any query-errors. If you add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` as well, you cannot ignore errors either.

Comment: Looks like `$dateTimeStart="$start_date.' '.$start_time";` is a bit wrong, those double quotes shouldn't be there, around the string. Either drop the singlequote and period, or drop the doublequote.

Comment: the problem is the query.. specifically i think its because of the datetime format.. that where the mistake is

Comment: Like I said, the `$dateTimeStart` and `$dateTimeEnd` variables are incorrectly defined. You're concating, but then using double quotes. Choose one.

Comment: `'(SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE firstname='$stud_first' AND lastname='$stud_last')'` is a SQL string, not a SQL query, also open to SQL injections. The quote here -> `firstname='` <- should actually break the string and throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the quotes around subselect:

```
       $sql="INSERT INTO appointment (prof_id, student_id, app_start, app_end) VALUES ('$prof_id', (SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE firstname='$stud_first' AND lastname='$stud_last'), '$dateTimeStart', '$dateTimeEnd');";
```